# First query on Amazon Athena results in "INVALID_INPUT". Why?

Tags: amazon-athena

I just set up Amazon Athena.
Any query I try results in: INVALID_INPUT

Could anyone please help?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I change the location of the data and bucket to Europe, it works. Not sure why.